# Android ¿Como refrescar un drawer menu (Menu lateral)?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo un drawer menu el cual le asigno unos datos, pero para poder ver el resultado tengo que cerrar la aplicación y volverla a abrir de nuevo, por lo que he estado buscando la forma de actualizar el drawer menu (Menu lateral) para ver los cambios sin necesidad de cerrar la app. ¿Que debo hacer o usar para poder resolver esta situación?.
De antemano gracias.
He intentado refrescarlo de esta manera desde el metodo que cambia los datos del drawer menu

```
((LeftMenuActivity) activity).updateDrawer();
```

Comment: Hola, deberías agregar tu código y lo que has intentado.

Comment: æ devjav, si deseas puedes agregar tu código para que comentemos como  implementar lo que indico en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El Navigation Drawer generalmente carga un listado de datos en un Adapter, lo que tienes que realizar es simplemente actualizar los datos dentro de este Adapter, y llamas el método [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) para actualizar los datos dentro del `DrawerLayout`:

por ejemplo  :

```
public void updateDrawer(){           
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      
       mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Elenasys , una duda, ¿de donde se obtiene el adapter?, en mi draw menu no lo tengo.

Comment: Agrega el código que carga tu menú (Drawer layout)